# RegEx for all letters (including Chinese, Greek, etc.)

Tags: regex, firefox, unicode

I need a regex that also matches Chinese, Greek, Russian, ... letters. 
What I basically want to do is remove punctuation and numbers.

Until now I removed punctuation and numbers "manually" but that does not seem to be very consistent.

Another thing I have tried is

```
/[\p{L}]/
```

but that is not supported by Mozilla (I use this in a Firefox extension).

Comment: Do you need to just match letters according to the particular user's language (which just means you need a locale aware regex engine) or do you need to match anything that is a letter in any possible language?

Comment: And which punctuation do you need to remove? Do you need to remove the apostrophe in O'Brien?

Comment: `[\p{P}\p{N}]` describes punctuation and numbers.

Comment: Thanks for that great question. I would also like that, but was sure it was not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you given [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) and the [Unicode plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) a try/look?

```
<script src="xregexp.js"></script>
<script src="xregexp-unicode.js"></script>
<script>
    var unicodeWord = XRegExp("^\\p{L}+$");
    alert(unicodeWord.test("Ниндзя")); // -> true
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Though, I don't really want to include a 8kb library that I only use once in my extension. 
The unicode ranges in the Unicode plugin are very helpful and I think I will use those to write something myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot complains about the current ECMA specs on regular expressions not dealing with unicode characters the way they should. E.g. a [blog entry by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizedRegularExpressions.aspx) that links back to a SO question ;-)
There's no "real" solution to this problem yet, but take a look at the answers of [Javascript + Unicode regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode) (your question is more or less a duplicate of this) (edit: I take that back, the unicode plugin Jonathan Lonowski suggests look pretty nice)